# req.query resulting in empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

req.query keeps resulting in an empty object.

I get rerouted to a page that says BAD_NULL_ER because name cannot be null (as I set it up schema that way), but when I refresh, the item I attempted to insert actually gets added to the database.

Here's the request

```
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let param = `name=${form.elements.name.value}&reps=${form.elements.reps.value}&weight=${form.elements.weight.value}&date=${form.elements.date.value}&lbs=${form.elements.lbs.value}`;

    req.open("POST", "/?" + param, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    req.send("/?" + param);
```

Here is the route

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.query);
  var sql = "INSERT INTO workouts(`name`, `reps`, `weight`, `date`, `lbs`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  connection.query(sql,
    [req.query.name, req.query.reps, req.query.weight, req.query.date, req.query.lbs],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
        return;
      }
      res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });
});
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Are you using body-parser pkg into your express server ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using body-parser

Comment: @Milad If you notice the console, the entire req.query is empty hence no wonder the error from MySQL happened. Or is it not the corresponding log statement?

Comment: Yes. I noticed. That's the issue I'm trying to fix.

Comment: You might be getting duplicate requests from the browser, and one comes empty (no query). You should gate your logic with `if (!req.query) return;`. Further, this code  is vulnerable to sql-injection, you should sanitize your input!

Comment: Ahh yes. The problem appears to be duplicate request. Although I used this code to check:
```
if (Object.keys(req.query).length === 0) {
    return;
  }
```
The code you suggested didn't necessarily work. But your input helped me solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to your app. It's the easiest way to work with it.